# error: cannot declare variable ‘t’ to be of abstract type ‘T’

Tags: c++

I'm learning c++ by myself and had problem to find error in class, which I didn't get.

Please help me, to find errors, I will be so glad. I know it maybe easy question.

```
class Base
{
public:
        virtual void g()=0;
};


class T:public Base
{
public:
        void func(){T t;}
        T*  h() const {return this;}
private:
        int b;
};
```

Comment: Your `T` class doesn't implement abstract `g` method. Thus it is abstract as well. And you cannot instantiate abstract classes. Also you may want to work a bit on naming.

Comment: Please, can u add right code in part of answer.

Comment: You need to implement `g`. Or not instantiate `T`. But how would I know what `g` is supposed to do? Or what exactly you are trying to achieve? It is impossible to write "right code" because this is a design issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed the definition part of `virtual void g()` in class `T`, which caused the class `T` to be an [abstract class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/abstract_class) (Defines an abstract type which cannot be instantiated but can be used as a base class.). Add the definition of `virtual void g()` should work:

```cpp
class T: public Base
{
public:
        void func(){T t;}
        T*  h() {return this;}
        virtual void g() {}
private:
        int b;
};
```

For the function `T*  h() const {return this;}`, it failed to build, can consider change into these two functions

```cpp
const T* h() const { return this; }
T* h() { return this; }
```

For the const function, we return the const pointer. For the non-const function, we return the non-const pointer type.

[Online demo](https://godbolt.org/z/75r4MfdWP)